# Why is the Bootstrap class not being applied?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-web-api

In the default/generic html provided in an ASP.NET app, the home page is rendered with the html in Index.cshtml, which starts out:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

This creates a "jumbotronified" section at the top of the page with a large "ASP.NET" within it.

However, when I try to use that bootstrap css class ("jumbotron") in another place:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("<html>");
builder.Append("<head>");
builder.Append("<title>");
builder.Append(string.Format("Available Delivery Performance Reports For 
{0}", unit));
builder.Append("</title>");
builder.Append("</head>");
builder.Append("<body>");

builder.Append("<div class=\"jumbotron\">");
builder.Append(String.Format("<h1>{0}</h1>", unit.ToUpper()));
builder.Append("</div>");
. . .
builder.Append("</table>");
builder.Append("</body>");
builder.Append("</html>");

return builder.ToString();
```

I get nothing special - the jumbotronned h1 is rendered, but without the jumbotron "effect" I would think that if the bootstrap classes are available from one place in the project, they would be available anywhere in the project. What do I need to do to introduce this dynamic html to the bootstrap subsystem?

Comment: I do not see **bootstrap.min.css** and **bootstrap.min.js** inside StringBuilder.

Comment: how did you include the bootstrap library?

Comment: @Aziz: I thought it was already included, as it is being used on the home page.

Comment: How do you render dynamic html tag inside existing html tag? Are you using iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (referencing the bootstrap and jQuery CDNs) works:

```
. . .
builder.Append("</title>");
builder.Append("<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />");
builder.Append("<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>");
builder.AppendFormat("<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js\" integrity=\"sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>");
builder.Append("</head>");
. . .
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are generating CSS for an entire new page (i.e. one that doesn't inherit from a Layout and isn't a partial view).

If that is the case, then you would need to explicitly referencing your Bootstrap files within this new generated page in order for them to be applied properly :

You could probably use something like :

```
// Example of adding in Bootstrap CSS
builder.AppendFormat("<link href='{0}' rel='stylesheet' />", Url.Content("~/Style/bootstrap.min.css"));
// Example of appending jQuery JS
builder.AppendFormat("<script src='{0}'></script>",Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"));
// Example of appending Bootstrap JS
builder.AppendFormat("<script src='{0}'></script>",Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));
builder.Append("</head>");
```

Traditionally, these files would be referenced within a Layout or within the `<head>` section of a normal view, however since you are manually building the entire HTML content within your `StringBuilder`, you need to include any references in there as well.

Comment: It was a typo, sorry. It should be [**Url.Content**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) instead.

Comment: Same thing with Url.Content. "Url." only affords me "Equals" and "ReferenceEquals". The "Url" that is recognized/automatically used is "System.Security.Policy.Url" Is ther a different one I should be using?

Comment: Are you using MVC? If so, the Url.Content() method should be available within the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace. You can try adding a using statement to include that.

If you are using Web Forms, you can use the alternative option, which is [**ResolveUrl()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I commented out "using System.Security.Policy.Url" (which I did not explicitly add), and add "using System.Web.MVC" but it is grayed out. When I add "System.Web.Mvc." I see "UrlHelper" and "UrlParameter" but am being prompted to import System.Security.Policy.Url